# Predict with linear model from another table with R

Tags: r, predict

Hi all I am new to R and I need to know how to use the predict function with tables.

I have a first table with some weather variables (`wind, temperature, pressure`) and with the `consumption` of a building. I have created a lineal model doing this:

```
mymodel<-lm(energyConsum ~ temperature + pressure+ wind, data=mytable)
```

And I have a second table with the weather prediction, with the values `temperature, wind and pressure` variables, and I want to predict the `consumption`

I know that I have to use the function `predict()`, and set `mymodel`, but I don't really know how to do it to create a new column with all the predictions (by line).

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your data, but here's an example with `mtcars`.

You can use `predict.lm`'s second argument, `newdata`, to make predictions on a data.frame.  You can then assign these results to a new column.

Example:

```
train <- mtcars[1:20, ]
test  <- mtcars[21:32,]

mymodel   <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data=train)
test$pred <- predict(mymodel, test)
```